# Not able to specify - MSbuild:OutDir as a variable

Tags: msbuild, outdir

I am trying to set up a command line build (currently using TFS build & moving to Jenkins based build). MsBuild's `OutDir` parameter does not seem take `%MainPath%` argument correctly.

```
set MainPath="C:\Users\jayapraa\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\" 
set MSBuildPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\"

cd %MSBuildPath%

msbuild.exe "C:\Users\jayapraa\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1.sln" /t:Build /p:OutDir=%MainPath%;Configuration=Release;Platform=x64;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.7.1
```

[image: image of error]

Comment: Why are you using the old msbuild in .net framework? use the version in 2017 (msbuild/bin subfolder of VS installation)

Comment: Same issue with the MSBuild version 15.0.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe you can separate the `/p:` values.  I would try to decompose them into separate switches (especially the one that is generating an error) to see if it helps.

Comment: I began with passing different /p args. It was not working. Then I took this syntax from another stackoverflow post.  It worked for hardcoded paths.

Comment: set "baseName=C:\Output\Full Build\Full Build-%Year%%Month%%Day%-"               -  setting the variable within quotes made it work..

Answer (score 0):

set "baseName=C:\Output\Full Build\Full Build-%Year%%Month%%Day%-" - setting the 
variable within quotes made it work..

MSBuild.exe "Mtell.Reservoir.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:OutDir="%baseName%%n%";